# A question in React+TypeScript+WebPack with typings-for-css-modules-loader

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

webpack.config.js

```
 {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [
      "style-loader",
      {
        loader: "typings-for-css-modules-loader",
        options: {modules: true,nameExport: true,camcelCase: true,sass: true}
      },
      "sass-loader"
    ]
  }
```

when I run 'npm run dev',error happend.
And when I modify the index.scss file,no declare file like 'index.scss.d.ts' to created.

> Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/typings-for-css-modules-loader/lib/index.js):
>
> Error:
> Cannot find module 'css-loader/locals' at
> Function.Module._resolveFilename
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)

Can you tell me how to fix it?
thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I fix it.Update css-loader v2.0 to v1.0.That is ok!
[here](https://github.com/Jimdo/typings-for-css-modules-loader/issues/85)

Comment: Is it updated from v1 to v2? I am still having troubles on v3.6? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

He means degrade to v1.0 ... Even now in 2021, the problem is still there, you have to choose between latest css-loader and typings-for-css-modules-loader...  I checked the github repository and found the project hasn't been upgrated for 4years

Comment: Very helpful knowing this is abandonware. Is there something comparable to this loader that can be used instead?